# Get all fixed drives names to a string array

Tags: c#

I want to get all the fixed drives names as a string array to give names for radio buttons..
this is the code i have used..

```
var drvs = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();
int hdcount = 0;
string[] drivenames;
foreach (var drv in drvs)
{
    if (drv.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.Fixed)
    {
        drivenames[hdcount] = drv.Name;
        hdcount++;
    }
}
```

But this code does not work.
it says "Error  1   Use of unassigned local variable 'drivenames'"

whats the wrong with my code ? how can i fix this ?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? You need to put an array in your variable.  (also, you should use `List<string>`)

Comment: @SLaks Can you please comment the code ?

Comment: @Astro Could you please first answer SLaks's question? The error is pretty straightforward and obvious. It says EXACTLY what's wrong - what is it exactly you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just declared the array `string[] drivenames;`, but you need to allocate the space required for the drive names, `string[] drivenames = new string[fixedDriveCount];` but this is a bit unpractical because you should know the number of fixed drives before. Also there are more powerfull objects to store a collection of items that don't require to know the number of items to store in the collection before hand. I suggest to use a `List<string>` instead

```
    var drvs = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    List<string> drivenames = new List<string>();
    foreach (var drv in drvs)
    {
        if (drv.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.Fixed)
        {
            drivenames.Add(drv.Name);
        }
    }
    int hdcount = drivenames.Count;
```

And with Linq you could shorten everything to

```
var drvs = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
           .Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
           .Select(k => k.Name).ToList();

// and then use the result to initialize a listbox (for example)
listBox1.DataSource = drvs;
```

Comment: you should take out the foreach in the Linq example because without it you can show how Linq "doesn't need" a loop.

Comment: It is just to show the results, not needed for the operation to extract the drive names's

Comment: Right changed example

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it Linqy

```
String []dArray = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
            .Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
            .Select(d => d.Name).ToArray();
```

or

```
List<string> dList = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
            .Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
            .Select(d => d.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to initialize your string array. You can do this by using the number of drives.

Try

```
var drvs = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();
int hdcount = 0;
string[] drivenames = new string[drvs.Count()];
foreach (var drv in drvs)
{
    if (drv.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.Fixed)
    {
        drivenames[hdcount] = drv.Name;
        hdcount++;
    }
}
```